# Interactive search filter for HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know there are many great plugins on the Net nowadays. But due to safety issues, external plugin are restricted. Thus, I wrote some JavaScript for an interactively searchable HTML table. The main features I need are a vertically scrollable table and interactive filtering. Since the window size is not fixed, I also added width adjustments.

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/72/)

1. Can someone please check if there are any parts I can refine OR that should be fixed? (i.e. I should define this as a var, etc.)
2. I have replaced `$("table#table-body tr:gt(0)").each()` to `$(row + ":gt(0)").each()`, is the code still correct (note: `var bodyTr = $(row + ":visible:eq(0) td");`)?

**JavaScript**

```
//Perparing table
/*
*comment
*/
$("<div>", {class: "tablewrapper"}).insertBefore("table#table-body");
$("<table>", {class: "header"}).appendTo($("<div>", {class: "headerwrapper"}).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
$("table#table-body").appendTo($("<div>", {class: "bodywrapper"}).appendTo("div.tablewrapper"));
$("table#table-body>thead").clone().val("").appendTo("table.header");
$("table.header>tr").removeClass("header_hidden");
$("table#table-body").find("thead tr").addClass("header_hidden");
$("table#table-body").find("tbody td:nth-child(2)").addClass("lefty");
$("<input>", {type: "text"}).attr("id","search-criteria").appendTo($("<div>", {class:"s_box"}).insertAfter("div.headerwrapper"));
$("<div>").attr("id","count").insertAfter("div.s_box");


resizeTable();
var bodyTd = $("table#table-body tr td");

$(window).resize(resizeTable);

//search function
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
    return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
}).toLowerCase();
var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";

if (keyword !== "") {
    $(row).each(function () {
        var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        //shorthand if function
        $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
    var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
    if (srowCount === 0) {
        if(!$(row).last().hasClass('s_empty'))
        {
            $("table#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Search not found</td></tr>');
        }
        $("tr.s_empty").show();
    } else {
        $("tr.s_empty").remove();
    }
} else {
    $("tr.s_empty").remove();
    $(row).show();
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
}

});

    var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";
    var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;

function resizeTable() {
    //width adjustments
    $("table.header").width($("#table-body").width());
    $("div.s_box").width(($("div.headerwrapper").width()-10)).height(($("table.header").height()-9));
    $("input#search-criteria").width(($("div.headerwrapper").width()-30)).height(($("div.s_box").height()-0.05));
    var counter_h = ($("table.header").height()/2+$("table.header").height()-1);
    $("div#count").css({"top":counter_h});

    var bodyTr = $("table#table-body tbody>tr:visible:eq(0) td");
    console.log(bodyTr);
    $("table.header tr:first th").each(function (index, value) {
        $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
    });

    //apply widths to every TD
    $("table#table-body tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
        $(this).children().each(function (index) {
            $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
        });
    });
}
```

**CSS**

```
div.tablewrapper, div.headerwrapper, div.bodywrapper {
    border:0px;
}

div.headerwrapper {
    background-color:#1BA7F5;    
}

div.bodywrapper {
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #1BA7F5;
}

table.header, table#table-body {
    border:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

table.header {
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#1BA7F5; 
    color:#FFF;
}

table.header th {
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table#table-body {
    width:100%;
}

table#table-body tr {
    line-height:30px;
    border-top:1px solid #C4C4C4;
}

table#table-body tr.header_hidden {
    display:none;
}

table#table-body tr:hover {
    background-color:#FFFF99;
}

div.s_box {
padding: 5px 5px;
background: #c4c4c4;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

input#search-criteria {
-webkit-appearance: none;
padding: 0 10px;
border: none;
border-radius: 6px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 23px;
background: #fff;
}

input#search-criteria:focus{
    outline:none;
}

div#count {
position: absolute;
right: 17px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #9EB4C2;
line-height: 19px;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 0 5px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

table#table-body tbody td.lefty {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code like this should be encapsulated and written in a way, so that it can be applied to any table, possibly even multiple tables on the same page. Currently you are putting everything in the global namespace and limiting yourself to a specific table by hard coding the id `table-body` (and using more IDs in the code).

You should instead consider implementing it as a jQuery plugin.

---

```
$(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

Can be simplified to

```
$(this).closest(row).toggle(td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1);
```

Comment: Thank you RoToRa. I understand what you are saying, although I am not skilled and knowledge enough yet to do that yet. 1 month ago, I knew pretty much nothing about JavaScript. Hope you can understand and that is also why I am trying to ask people to review it. ... thanks for the if > toggle. this is the use of .toggle( display ) right? (just read it on JQuery API now.)  PS. if it is not too much, can you explain how I can encapsulate it? Perhaps I can try it myself from your example/explanation. Unless you are super kind and decide to review it.

Comment: RoToRa, I have tried to create a few new lines (1-21) if i didn't misunderstand what you are saying about encapsulating. 1) Is that the right idea, 2) how would I place the original parts into function (a) now?